# How to remove Laravel public folder after redirect from http on Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I am try to remove the `public` folder from my URL. 
I already try to search for answer but no luck, quite similar question are [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/816392/lets-encrypt-automatically-redirect-to-https-not-working) and [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/420272/apache-redirect-from-http-to-https-not-working).

Here the detail of my dev environment:

- Ubuntu 14.x
- Apache 2.x
- Laravel 5.3
- PHP 5.3.x
- [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) (SSL Certificate)

When I am setting up my domain certificate using Let's Encrypt it generated an Apache config file that will automatically redirect any request from `http` to `https` called `le-redirect-example.com.conf`, as below

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
ServerSignature Off

Redirect permanent / https://example.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]


ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redirect.error.log
LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

I have several Laravel applications as subfolder under the `/var/www/html` document root, inside `/var/www/html` already has a `.httaccess` that configure the redirection, the content as follow:

```
    Options -Indexes

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

...    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com/public/$1 [L]

...
```

I have omitted irrelevant lines.

My Laravel application full path in question as follow:

```
/var/www/html/example.com
```

The last `.htaccess` file is inside the `example.com/public/` the content as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

The last `.httaccess` file is the vanilla file from the Laravel project, no modification done.

So, here is the thing, when I key in

`http://example.com`

it will redirected to

`https://example.com/example.com/public`

What I am hoping is that when I key in

`http://example.com`

it will be simply redirected to

`https://example.com`

I already try to put this rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

on those files but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just let your webserver config do the job. Just you need to point your domains directly to public directory of Laravel. What i did for my project is `mydomain.com/first_app` point to `/var/www/html/first_app/public` and similarly `mydomain.com/another_app point` to `/var/www/html/another_app/public`

Comment: Thank for the reply @shailesh-singh, will try it soon. I still don't quite understand .htaccess works.

Comment: Change `R=301` to `R`, could be caused by caching issues?